# Delete not working with @RenderPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working with MVC3 (code first) and came across something peculiar. This happens when I want to delete a question. When I write the page with all aspects of the question it works fine, but since I need the same thing in several pages I thought I put it in a seperate page and put in in the page with `@RenderPage`.

When I do it with option one, the delete works perfectly, but when I do it with the second option, the delete doesn't work. Could someone please explain me how this can be and if I can fix it so I can use the `@RenderPage`.

For clarification I'll give some code:

Option 1

```
<div class="Question">
    <div class="QuestionHeader">
        <div class="QuestionTitle">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</div>
        <div class="QuestionDate">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Message)</div>
    <div class="spacing">
    <hr />
    <div class="QuestionAuthor>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Author)</div>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <p class="bottomNav">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

Option 2

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_InitQuestion.cshtml")
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <p class="bottomNav">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

(I don't think there are any here, but if you see a typo: sorry, but I couldn't copy/paste the code since I'm not writing from my work computer. I'm pretty sure there aren't any typo's in the code on my computer. I see the question details just fine with the `@RenderPage`, I just can't delete it (won't go into the controller's `ActionResult`, `HttpPost` part of delete))

Comment: You might need to specify controller/action inside Html.BeginForm. As well are you not passing any parameters in your form, so you ActionResult probably doesn't have a clue of which question you are deleting.

Comment: he does know which question. I have an overview of all questions seperated by status. Only unanswered questions can be deleted so in that table there is an ActionLink with parameters ("Delete", "Delete", new{id=item.QuestionID}. If you click that link you go to the details (the page above with the delete button that's not working). Also in both ActionResults (get and post) he gets the id of the question. Like I said, whithout @RenderPage the delete works just fine. But I'll try the FormMethod.Post.

Comment: adding FormMethod.Post to Html.BeginForm doesn't help. Also putting Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Questions", FormMethod.Post) does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why (so if someone could explain it, please do), but for some reason something went horribly wrong with the @RenderPage. I first coded option 1, ran it and copy/pasted the source code and then did the same with option 2. Compared both and saw that for some reason there was't a form tag with option 2 (the @RenderPage).

Someone suggested to use Partial in stead of RenderPage and it worked. So now my code is:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_InitQuestion.cshtml", Model)
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p class="bottomNav">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Htlm.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

Comment: I justed heared something about a bug in earlier versions of MVC (don't know if it's fixed in MVC 4)

Comment: The partial is indeed written as follow: @Html.Partial("_InitQuestion", Model). Thanks for the tip ePezhman!

Answer (score 0):

User Html.Partial instead of RenderPage and you don't need to right the whole path to the view. and when you submit a form some input with the it's specific name is being passed to the action, you have nothing in the form and passing nothing to the action, how does it supposed to know what do delete?

```
@Html.Partial("_InitQuestion", Model)
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p class="bottomNav">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        <input type="hidden" value="@(Model.Id)" name="Id" />
        @Htlm.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index")
    </p>
}
```